# What happens with transactions e and f in this example?

Tags: transaction, tangle, double-spending

I was looking at the best answer of the following thread ([Without the Coordinator, how will the network decide which double-spend succeeds?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1100)) and asking myself what will happen to the transactions *e*, *f* and all previous ones in the red zone?

Will they never be confirmed again because *j* is an "old tip" now?

Wouldn't be that bad for this transactions?

Comment: _"Will they never be confirmed again because j is an "old tip" now?"_ You should use the term "approved" instead of "confirmed". There is an important difference. "approved" means that the transaction was checked by another transaction and seen as a valid. "confirmed" means that the probability for this transaction to be valid is so huge (i.e. approved by so many tips) that we can say it is _confirmed_

Answer (score 2):

In this [example](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/1100/without-the-coordinator-how-will-the-network-decide-which-double-spend-succeeds?newreg=293942708346428bb6eacb27b89a65f7), transactions X, K, L, Q, R, a, b, e, f, j must be **re-attached** to other transactions to get a new opportunity to be confirmed (promoting will not help because promotion don't change trunk and branch transaction).

Note that X is now conflicting with all tips: so re-attachment will also fail forever for X.

So, yes regarding confirmation speed: being attached-to or validating (directly or indirectly) a transaction that will later be revealed as a "double-spend" is not a good thing: it reduces confirmation speed and force a re-attachment.